# How do I find a good fit

Tags: fitting

I have the following [data set:](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vezfqekcofibsxf/thedata.m?dl=0) A plot of it looks like this:[image] This looks, to an untrained observer like a slightly-smaller-than a semicircle, but trying to fit this using `NonlinearModelFit[]` produces fairly junky output 
$$\sqrt{715787.\, -1.40519 (x-1742.99)^2}+1875.84$$
Any ideas for how to do this better?

Comment: Are you certain it's supposed to be a circle, or could it be an ellipse?

Comment: @J.M. I am certainly not certain :) I doubt it is an ellipse  whose major axis is the $x$-axis, because it does not appear to be orthogonal to the $x$-axis, but I certainly agree that it could be a shifted ellipse. I am wary of having too many parameters, though... Any suggestions you have would be appreciated.

Comment: How was the data collected?  One experimental unit measured at equal intervals over time?  And what about the regularly spaced "bumps" ?  Do those need to be modeled, too?

Comment: How come the data is one dimensional?

Comment: @Feyre Do you mean "apparently perfectly symmetrical" ?

Comment: @JimBaldwin No, though good catch. The data is a single list, with no x-values.

Comment: @JimBaldwin The data is experimental (OK, it's a computational experiment, no actual environment has been harmed), and I am guessing that the bumps are random fluctuation, so I am guessing that the fit should be to a convex curve.

Comment: @Feyre The $x$ values are $1, 2, \dotsc, $ That's pretty common usage.

Comment: @JimBaldwin and the reason the data is perfectly symmetrical is that the numbers are logs of absolute values of coefficents of "reciprocal" (palindromic) polynomials - the reciprocal-ness is a prior.

Comment: @Feyre `NonlinearModelFit` and `LinearModelFit` (and maybe others) assume the `x` values are 1,2,..., if you give those functions a one-dimensional vector.  I'm old-school and would prefer such functional conveniences not to be used (i.e., having the data set be explicitly defined).

Comment: @JimBaldwin I'd always set it explicitly when sharing the data too, I've seen mistakes happen, hence the ask. OCD is the better part of error reduction.

Comment: @IgorRivin Can I ask the explicit code you're using? `NonlinearModelFit[data, Sqrt[a - b (x - c)^2] + d, {a, b, c, d}, x]` craps out on me.

Comment: @Feyre `nlm = NonlinearModelFit[theData, 
  Sqrt[a^2 + b (x + c)^2] + d, {a, b, c, d}, x]`

Comment: @Feyre and yes, putting minuses in front of some parameters make the fit fail completely, so this functionality does not seem quite ready for prime time, so maybe there is something better...

Comment: There's code posted on this site for performing orthogonal fitting of a circle. The elliptic case is a bit harder to do IIRC, and I'll have to look the algorithm up to implement it. That's why I was asking.

Comment: `Findfit[]` works a bit better, but it is a bit funky depending on the initial values, I agree with @J.M. that maybe the model isn't accurate. `FindFit[data, 
  Sqrt[a^2 + b (x + c)^2], {{a, 120}, {b, -0.5}, {c, -128}}, x]`

Comment: I'm certainly curious at to what palindromic polynomials you're considering. A likely simpler one from what you're using appears to be much "smoother":  `ListPlot[Log[CoefficientList[(x + 1)^256, x]]]`.

Comment: @JimBaldwin Sure, it's here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/b5xulhz9mi4tio4/random-space-plane%20%286%29.pdf?dl=0

Answer (score 5):

Using

```
(x - a)^2/b^2 + (y - c)^2/d^2 == 1
```

for the equation of an ellipse (as at least 4 parameters are needed for approximating this data) the following code provides an approximation to the data:

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, c + (d Sqrt[-a^2 + b^2 + 2 a x - x^2])/b, 
{{a, 128}, {b, 128}, {c, 0}, {d, 126}}, x]
Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[nlm[x], {x, 1, 256}, PlotStyle -> Red]]
nlm["BestFitParameters"] // Normal
(* {a -> 128., b -> 135.977, c -> -54.5663, d -> 176.943} *)
```

[image: Ellipse fit]

However (and this might just be a semantics issue) I'm calling this an "approximation" to the data rather than a "fit" in that there really is no random error and apparent features of the data are ignored in the approximation.  But it is a subject matter decision as to whether the approximation is good enough.  I certainly wouldn't take the standard errors of the parameter estimates seriously.

**Addition**

To help decide on whether the approximation is good enough plotting the residuals vs. the predictor variable can be informative as to the size of the approximation error and if there are any patterns that might be eliminated with a more complex prediction function.

```
ListPlot[nlm["FitResiduals"], Joined -> True]
```

[image: Residual plot]

Comment: A question: how robust is this with respect to the starting points? For example, I noticed you chose $d=126$...

Comment: That was just close to the maximum y-value.  I assume you ask this because you have other datasets to approximate.  Even using a starting value as low as 25 gets the "correct" solution.

Comment: I'll argue that a good fit removes the dents, because they are known to be faulty points.